ADG849 Analog Switch Circuit Failure Analysis
I've designed a tester for one of my products and part of what the tester does is provides one of two voltages to my unit under test. The two voltages are generated by a sub-circuit shown below, based on TI LM317EMP/NOPB adjustable regulator and an Analog Devices ADG849 Analog Switch. Everything actually works fine at first, and continues to work normally for several sessions of being used, but I've had several of these testers now, due to some condition that I haven't been able to isolate, exhibit the same basic failure mode. The tester state is irreversible (a hard failure) without replacing the analog switch IC5.
I'm here asking for help diagnosing this failure mode, and for a suggestions for possible solution to eliminating it.

With a unit under test installed, the current draw is normally ~30mA, and this jumps to ~150mA when failed.
In the failed condition, the analog switch (IC5) is a bit hot to the touch, and its voltage output is not a reflection of either of the two input voltages.
In its failed condition, the analog switch (IC5) does change in response to the adjustable regulator output changing. This is all with no load, VCC and BATTERY_IN are open circuits. The only explanation I can come up with for that is that the analog switch is acting like a voltage divider in its failed state.
For what it's worth, the 5V net is the output of an On Semi NCP1117LPST50T3G 5V linear regulator.


POWER_IN is ostensibly 6.5V, and IC1 is intended to generate either ~4.9V or ~3.3V depending on the state of VSEL1 and VSEL2. Battery_In and VCC are two different test points on the unit under test, and represent different power inputs (which are diode-OR'd on the unit under test). The Analog Switch (IC5) is simply meant to route the adjustable voltage to one of those two test points on the unit under test. Jumper JP10 is not intended to be installed or removed while the tester is powered on, but I can't be 100% confident in that, and I would hope that the analog switch could cope with that it in any case. C4 and C5 are tantalum capacitors and C2 and C3 are ceramics, but again I can't see how that would matter either.
VSEL1 and VSEL2 are both pulled down, and the valid configurations are such that only one of VSEL1 and VSEL2 are high (5V) as seen here.

One other note, and or disclosure, I had the current limit set to 800mA on the bench power supply that provides the 6.5V input to the tester, and I read that the analog switch is rated for 400mA continuous. The units under test don't normally consume anywhere near that current. So I just turned the power supply current limit down to 250mA to provide adequate headroom (the unit under test operates at 3.3V, so 250mA * 4.5V/3.3V = 340mA < 400mA). Maybe that's the explanation and the solution right there. Still would appreciate any advice on the making the tester design more tolerant / resilient within reason.

Are you applying power to the other switch terminals when the switch's Vdd is 0?

@vir The switch common terminal is the output of the adjustable regulator. The other terminals route to the UUT power inputs. I don't see a way that the UUT could source power to those pins without the common being powered. The switch's Vdd is +5V output from a fixed 5V regulator on the tester, I guess it's possible the fixed regulator comes up slower than the adjustable regulator (plus the UUT onboard switching regulator) but that feels unlikely?

So the LM317 output is uncontrolled until MCU boots and activates one of the FETs? Is the 5V generated from power_in too?

@Justme, the FET inputs are pulled down. The microcontroller boots and then sets them "one-hot" yes.

@vicatcu You don't think the LM317 outputing as high voltage as it can does not damage the mux? You can't exceed the mux supply (whatever it is, 0V or 5V).

@Justme, it can't exceed the input voltage of 6.5V, right? ... and the switch has a absolute maximum rating of 7V, so I think it should be able to handle whatever condition might exist for a few tens of milliseconds after power up no? Oh wait, I see what you mean "Analog inputs maximum rating is Vdd+0.3V"

I would short Q1G$2 D-S permanently and replace R3 by a 1.05kΩ resistor.

@vicatcu Weird assumptions, but most importantly, from where does the 5V regulator gets the input, and what is on 5V node other than capacitor and MCU and mux supply?

The input to the switched terminals cannot exceed the power rail at any time. Some switches allow you to do this, but it is a feature that will be explicitly listed on the datasheet. "A few tens of milliseconds" may be ok, but it could also be what is causing your problem; milliseconds are an eternity as far as semiconductors are concerned.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany oh that's a good idea, kind of silly that I have a three-state control when I really only need a two-state control... and it eliminates the race condition Justme raised in comments

@Justme for completeness, the 5V regulator gets its input from the same 6.5V input that the adjustable regulator gets its input. And the 5V node is exclusively for the benefit of the analog switch and the microcontroller.

Thanks everyone for the feedback, very helpful

@vicatcu Four possible states, one of which is "HCF = Halt and Catch Fire".

It sounds like the analog mux gets damaged.
When you turn the power on, the LM317 putputs as high voltage it possibly can to mux analog input pin.
If the 5V is not yet up and running, the  clamp diodes inside the mux will pass current from the LM317 6V supply out to the 5V supply node, charging any capacitors on 5V node and powering any load.
Same applies even if 5V supply comes up first, but MCU has not yet booted - the LM317 output still tries to push current into the 5V supply node, as analog pins are rated only to be within the power supply voltages.
The VDD+0.3V and 30mA flow through the clamp is the absolute maximum rating when damage starts to happen. The mux does not have to work properly if you exceed the nominal ratings, but do not yet reach the absolute maximum ratings.

This feels like a plausible explanation, I'll spin the tester PCB and see how it goes, thanks for the second look!
